# adjacent positions of a board

Tags: python, list, tuples

Can anyone help me with this?

I have a board with columns(a,b,c) and rows(1,2,3) and I want to make a function that give me the adjacent positions of the positions I choose.

I have this:

```
def obtain_positions_adjacent(pos):
    adjacent = [
        [1, 3],
        [0, 2, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [0, 4, 6],
        [1, 3, 5, 7],
        [2, 4, 8],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 6, 8],
        [5, 7]
    ]
    return adjacent[pos]
```

This return me an Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.

I've tried this too:

```
    def obtain_positions_adjacent(pos):
        return tuple((cria_posicao(adj[0], adj[1])
            for adj in ((obter_pos_x(pos)+dx, obter_pos_y(pos)+dy)
                        for dx, dy in ((0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)))
            if (adj[0] >= 0 and adj[1] >= 0)))
```

But it's not working too.

I have a my creat_position(col,row) & position_to_str(pos);
And I want my output to be this:

```
>>> p1 = creat_position('a', '2')
>>> p2 = cria_posicao('b', '3')
>>> position_to_str(p1)
’a2’
>>> tuple(position_to_str(p) for p in obtain_positions_adjacent(p2))
(’b2’, ’a3’, ’c3’)
```

Comment: What argument are you calling `obtain_positions_adjacent` with?  The error is telling you that you are calling it with a tuple.  Array subscripting expects an intergeter.

Comment: my position wich is:
def creat_position(c, r):
    if isinstance(c, str) and c in ('a', 'b', 'c') and isinstance(l, str) and l in ('1', '2', '3'):
        return c, r 
& I have my def obtain_pos_c(pos):
    return pos[0]
&
def obtain_pos_r(pos):
    return pos[1]